# Do Navy Seals die in training?

Tags: military, warfare

I didn't know where to ask this but i've heard that sometimes Navy Seals die during traing? Is this true? The same goes fro Green Berets.

Comment: The answer to this is obviously yes, soldiers sometimes die during training (from causes related to their training). Even basic training is an extremely intense experience, and accidents do happen. And when those accidents involve firearms or any kind of explosives, the mortality rate can be significant.

Comment: a simple Google search turns up news articles about training accidents resulting in death, but i can't find anything about how common they are

Comment: How does this pertain to history specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was prophetic, coming as it did on May 16th. Here is a link to an article in the New York Post about an occurrence of this sort on May 17th.

http://www.myfoxny.com/story/22283938/navy-seal-from-long-island-dies-in-training-accident

It seems to happen "accidentally," as opposed to "overtraining," but yes, it does happen.

Comment: Thanks, my main question was whether it was from accidental causes or physical stress from training.